# Is there a way to extract a specific number of stocks with the highest Sharpe ratio from a large number of stocks?

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to extract the stocks with the highest Sharpe ratio using daily returns from 1/01/2018 to 31/01/2018 using R
So far I've managed to convert the data to a time series using

```
library(zoo)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
prices<-zoo(Project.Data.File,seq(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), to = as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = 1))
```

I am having trouble calculating the daily returns after this for further statistical calculations.
I've tried using

```
CalculateReturns(prices, method=c("discrete","log"))
```

But I received an error.
I am also confused as to how to deal with missing data. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please find the excel file attached to this post.
Thanks in advance!

[Blockquote](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NMg637KX5s9-DuKNe658iD56HYVBacDo/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try: `prices <- zoo(Project.Data.File[, -1], seq(...`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the problem now.

Comment: Use read.zoo rather than zoo.  It allows you to specify which column is the index column and defaults to 1 if you don't specify it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is quite informative. Your data is not numeric. This is because your original data has dates in the first column. Remove this column as you create your zoo object.

```r
library(zoo)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

prices <- zoo(Project.Data.File[,-1],seq(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), to = as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = 1))

stock_returns <- CalculateReturns(prices, "discrete")

head(stock_returns[,1:3])

           A2.MILK.CO.LTD ADELAIDE.BRIGHTON.LTD ABACUS.PROPERTY.GROUP
2018-01-01             NA                    NA                    NA
2018-01-02    0.017639077          -0.003067485           0.000000000
2018-01-03   -0.009333333          -0.003076923          -0.002427184
2018-01-04    0.009421265          -0.004629630          -0.012165450
2018-01-05    0.006666667           0.015503876          -0.002463054
2018-01-06    0.017218543           0.004580153           0.000000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been trying to figure this out all day.

Comment: Happy to help. If this has solved your issue, kindly mark the answer as accepted to help future users who might have a similar issue.